# Check if join stream was successful using Apache Spark - Scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, apache-kafka-streams

I am new to Apache Spark, using Scala. I am able to join a table to the stream using following command:

```
Updated_DF = Inbound_DF.join(colToAdd, colToAdd("key") <=> Inbound_DF("key"), "left")
    .withColumnRenamed("Data_DF","site").drop("Id","key")
```

Now I want to check if `colToAdd("key")` and `Inbound_DF("key")` matched and join was successful or not. For example, colToAdd:

```
Id   key     Data_DF
S31  S3   {"name":"nick","region":"IN"}
S21  S2   {"name":"john","region":"CA"}
S11  S1   {"name":"ashley","region":"CA"}
S51  S5   {"name":"bella","region":"UK"}
S41  S4   {"name":"kumar","region":"In"}
S6   S6   {"name":"ben","region":"US"}
P11  P1   {"name":"MKD","region":"UAE"}
P21  P2   {"name":"ahmad","region":"UAE"}
```

Message from incoming stream look like:

```
cusId  key  item  price
1897   S2   book   54
```

After join, the updated message should look like:

```
cusId  key  item  price    site
1897   S2   book   54    {"name":"john","region":"CA"}
```

But if I get a stream message with `key = S9`, the join will not happen and then I want to log a message:

```
------- join failed, key not found ---------
```

As far as I know, this can be achieved using the `filter` method but I am not sure how to implement that. Please help me how this can be done or is there any better way to do the same.

Comment: you are doing a leftjoin and it would always succeed and you will get all the data from the leftdataframe and matching data from the right dataframe.  Can you update the question with some sample data and the output that you expect?

Comment: Hey @NikunjKakadiya, I have updated the question.

Comment: Can you Please specify your both dataframe content . what you added does not help much to get an idea

Comment: @NikunjKakadiya, Updated.

Comment: Somehow I need to check if the message (after enrichment) is having that extra column `site` or not. If it's not present, then I need to log a statement.

Comment: check my answer that I posted

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways of doing it. I am just providing you with an idea of how this could be done and you can adjust according to your use case.

First the way you are doing the left join is incorrect, you need to swap the dataframes. The Stream dataframe should be left dataframe.

```
//Source data
val df = Seq(("S31","S3","""{"name":"nick","region":"IN"}"""),("S21","S2","""{"name":"john","region":"CA"}"""),("S11","S1","""{"name":"john","region":"CA"}""")).toDF("Id","Key","Data_DF")
val df1 = Seq((1897,"S2","book",54),(1920,"S9","movie",200)).toDF("custId","Key","item","price")
//initial join and the count of the records
val df2 = df1.join(df,Seq("Key"),"left").drop("Id").withColumnRenamed("Data_DF","site")
val initialjoincount = df2.count()
//filter and count of the records
val filteredDF = df2.filter($"site".isNotNull)
val filtereddfcount = filteredDF.count()
//compare both the counts and print message/log
if(filtereddfcount == initialjoincount)
{
  println("Join Happened")
}
else
{
  println("Value not found in stream.")
}
```

Comment: Getting this error saying: `org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Queries with streaming sources must be executed with writeStream.start()`

I think we cannot run these commands directly as we are getting data from a stream.